# why are there links to links in system directories?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, symlink

For example,

the executable `emacs`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Jun  9  2012 /usr/bin/emacs -> /etc/alternatives/emacs
llrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Jun  9  2012 /etc/alternatives/emacs -> /usr/bin/emacs23-x
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 May 16  2013 /usr/bin/emacs23 -> emacs23-x
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6772008 May 16  2013 /usr/bin/emacs23-x
```

the executable `emacsclient`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      29 Jun  9  2012 /usr/bin/emacsclient -> /etc/alternatives/emacsclient
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      28 Jun  9  2012 /etc/alternatives/emacsclient -> /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs23
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   18256 May 16  2013 /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs23
```

1. why are there links to links in system directories?

   If we need to link for some reason, in the examples, why links from a file in `/usr/bin` to  a file in `/etc/alternatives/` then back to a file in `/usr/bin`, rather than links the two files in `/usr/bin` directly?
2. is there a command that can deference a link until reaching a non-link file?

p.s. Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. why are there links to links in system directories?

It gives you a flexible way to chose what default program, or program version you will use. From `man update-alternative`:

> Debian's alternatives system aims to solve this problem.  A generic
>   name in the filesystem is shared by all files providing
>          interchangeable functionality.  The alternatives system and the system administrator together determine which  actual  file
>          is  referenced  by  this generic name.  For example, if the text editors ed(1) and nvi(1) are both installed on the system,
>          the alternatives system will cause the generic name /usr/bin/editor to refer to /usr/bin/nvi by default. The system 
>   admin‐
>          istrator  can  override  this and cause it to refer to /usr/bin/ed instead, and the alternatives system will not alter this
>          setting until explicitly requested to do so.

---

> 2, is there a command that can deference a link until reaching a non-link file?

If you have `readlink` utility, you can:

```
readlink -f link
```

Example:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/nawk
/usr/bin/gawk
```

Or you can use Perl `abs_path` function from core module `Cwd`:

```
$ perl -MCwd=abs_path -le 'print abs_path(shift)' /usr/bin/nawk 
/usr/bin/gawk
```

**Note**

- [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)
- [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink)

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the `alternatives` system.  It allows admins to configure various utilities that do the same (or similar) things as the default on that system.

Examples are configuring which version of Java is the system default - OpenJDK or Oracle's offering.

You can list the alternatives on your system using:

```
alternatives -l
```

You'll notice that all of those listed by this command are also in `/etc/alternatives` as symlinks.

The `namei` utility is useful for following symlinks:

```
$ namei /usr/bin/cdrecord
f: /usr/bin/cdrecord
 d /
 d usr
 d bin
 l cdrecord -> /etc/alternatives/cdrecord
   d /
   d etc
   d alternatives
   l cdrecord -> /usr/bin/wodim
     d /
     d usr
     d bin
     - wodim
```

Comment: If cdrecord is a link to wodim, then you do not have cdrecord but a defective fork that you should definitely avoid. There are more than 100 documentd bugs in that fork.

Comment: The original cdrtools is here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtools/files/